# Firewall rules to block unwanted protocols on given ports

Tags: network, firewalls, linux

Does somebody has an idea, that what kind of iptables/pf rule must i use to achieve this?:

i only want to allow these connections [on the output chain]:

on port 53 output only allow udp - dns
on port 80 output only allow tcp - http
on port 443 output only allow tcp - https
on port 993 output only allow tcp - imaps
on port 465 output only allow tcp - smtps
on port 22 output only allow tcp - ssh
on port 20-21 output only allow cp - ftp
on port 989-990 output only allow tcp - ftps
on port 1194 output only allow udp - OpenVPN

So that e.g.: OpenVPN on port 443 would be blocked, because only HTTPS is allowed on port 443 outbound.

Any ideas? :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at http://l7-filter.sourceforge.net/HOWTO

That describes how to use the "Layer 7" module in iptables rules for deep packet inspection.